# Jest: No file coverage available

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, istanbul, babel-jest

After updating to jest 22 and babel jest 22, I have the following error on every test suites:

```
Test suite failed to run

No file coverage available for: /src/store/__tests__/medias.js

at CoverageMap.fileCoverageFor (node_modules/istanbul-lib-coverage/lib/coverage-map.js:96:15)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

How can I fix that?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug.  Track the status at: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5109